# Using Zend Framework and Angular together

Tags: angular, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap-4

Are there any resources explaining how to use Zend Framework 3 (or ZF2) with Angular? (I want to totally replace jQuery).

In particular, I'm interested on suggested application structure, where to store angular conponents and zf views, how to use Apache instead of the server built in ng-cli, how to automatically transpile and build the app (eventually using PHPStorm instead ng build).

I can see, that there are already [Bootstrap 4 components based on Angular](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), so a guide on how to use Bootstrap 4 with ZF3 would be best.

Beginner. I've mastered Zend Framework 3 Skeleton Application and took Angular quickstart tutorial. I'm using PHPStorm so there are transpilers built in.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, that mix Zend Framework and Angular in one repository is a good solution. The common architecture here:

- you create an api service with Zend Framework (take a look on Apigility here https://apigility.org/);
- and you create front-end with Angular, which uses endpoints of your ZF back-end.

So they both are separate apps in separate repositories, but linked together through the ZF api. In that case you do not need to replace Apache or ng-cli (or npm). Each app will use its own instruments and environment.

Comment: This would work ok for ajax, but I need to connect Angular with ZF views and layouts  (eg. to add some eye candy stuff, and mostly, to have all js tested), have multiple output .js files (eg. one for not logged user, one app for admin etc.). What would be suggested directory tree and build system setup?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create Front End in separate module. You can follow **Apigility Admin UI**. It developed as separated module, loaded in Zend Project and keep using `view` from Zend Framework

https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin-ui

Comment: This is using AngularJS (Angular 1), I'm looking for setup for Angular v2.

Comment: Its the same, its not about version its basically about architecture which remains same for both the cases J